# why list() doesn't work in my case

Tags: php

Trying to create a php class for importing CSV data. Sorry for the messy looking codes. I created a function _santitize_product_list() to filter through the CSV file separating out the product data that pass the import requirement and product data that missing something. The function works fine if :

```
$this->_sanitized_data = $this->_sanitize_product_list($this->_csv_data);
```

So that I get an array that contains both group. If I want to separate them out, I try to use `list()`:

```
list($this->_sanitized_data, $this->_error_list) = $this->_sanitize_product_list($this->_csv_data);
```

this time the code returns Undefined offset: 1 error. My question is why list() doesn't work in this case?

```
class data_import_update {
    protected $_dbc;
    protected $_update;
    protected $_total_line;
    protected $_csv_data;
    protected $_sanitized_data;
    protected $_error_list;
    protected $_update_list;
    protected $_import_list;

    // constructor
    // plug in DB connection
    function __construct($csv_data) {

        $this->_csv_data = $csv_data;

        // step1. fiter the input data

        //list($this->_sanitized_data, $this->_error_list) = $this->_sanitize_product_list($this->_csv_data);
        $this->_sanitized_data = $this->_sanitize_product_list($this->_csv_data);
    } // End of Constructor

    // filter out items that no meet requirement
    private function _sanitize_product_list ($list_input) {
        $err_item = array();
        foreach ($list_input as $key => $item) {
            //require fields: product_sku, product_name, product_unit, product_packaging, category, file_url, slash in the category
            //make sure each item required fields aren't left empty
            // || empty($item['file_url']) empty($item['product_name']) || empty($item['product_packaging']) ||
            if (empty($item['product_sku']) || (empty($item['category']) || !strpos($item['category'], '/'))) {

                // log error item and unset it from import list
                $err_item[] = $list_input[$key]['product_sku'];
                unset($list_input[$key]);
            }
        } // End of foreach loop

        if (!empty($err_item[0])) {
            return array('import_list'=>$list_input, 'error_item'=>$err_item);
        }else {
            return array('import_list'=>$list_input);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your `else` when you `return array('import_list'=>$list_input);` there is only one item, index 0 and no item with index 1, but you've given `list()` two vars to populate.

Comment: the returned array output like this: Array
(
    [import_list] => Array
        (
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [publish] => 1
                    [product_sku] => BX4721 -BK
                               .........
                )    [error_item] => Array
        (
            [0] => BX3856
            [1] => BX4711-MX
            [2] => BX3856
        )

)

Comment: the `if` at the end sometimes returns  an array with 2 elements, sometimes just 1.

Comment: Why do you return an associative array if you plan on accessing them by position instead of by name?

Comment: hi, AbraCadaver, Thanks for quite reply. I do have two array to return. they are like array (import_list, error_Items)

Comment: Hi, Barmar. I am kind of new to php programming. I was planing to scan through the CSV and separate the good and bad data. And at the end, the good data get imported, and bad data get displayed so I know which product is imported and which need fix. So I put them in two class properties, this is why I want to use list() to output them.

Comment: Please tell me the simple and good practice doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list()` only works with numeric arrays, not associative arrays, because it assigns the first variable from `$array[0]`, the second variable from `$array[1]`, and so on. You also need to return 2 elements all the time. So change the `if` at the end to just:

```
return array($list_input, $err_item);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your if check on `$err_item` has an else condition that only returns one element in the array. I can only assume your code is hitting that return condition, so your `list()` call won't have a second parameter to use.